# Remove punctuation from a field in Postgres DB before using regex to query it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, activerecord

I can't find the answer to this and am really banging my head on the wall trying to work it out so any help much appreciated.

I have a company table and one of the companies is "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A.".

I want to remove all punctuation from the name (so "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A." becomes "JPMorgan Chase Bank NA")

This is the closest I've got:

```
Company.where("replace(name, '.', '') ILIKE ?", "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N A%")
=> [#<Company:0x00007ff8201f2b90 id: 25, name: "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A.", created_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 09:26:57 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 31 May 2021 09:26:57 UTC +00:00>]
```

This works but it only removes the `.` (I've left the comma in for the field that would be in the database). I want to remove all punctuation so I tried things like:

```
Company.where("replace(name, '.,-:', ' ') ILIKE ?", "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N A%")
Company.where("replace(name, '[.,-:]', ' ') ILIKE ?", "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N A%")
Company.where("replace(name, /[^[:word:]\s]/, ' ') ILIKE ?", "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N A%")
```

I can't seem to find out how to replace a range of characters with a single character

Answer (score 5):

Got it!

```
Company.where("regexp_replace(name, '[[:punct:]]', '', 'g') ILIKE ?", "JPMorgan Chase Bank NA%")
```

I needed to use `regexp_replace` and I needed to add the `g` as the final argument to it.

That was a head scratcher - I hope you've found this as a solution to your problem.